# Operator identity in Quantum mechanics

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

The question is :

If an operator $\hat{A}$ follows the property that $\hat{A}.\hat{A}=\mathbb{I}$  , where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity operator, then  prove that: $\exp(\theta \hat{A})=\cosh (\theta \mathbb{I}) + \sinh(\theta \hat{A})$, where $\theta$ is any scalar.

I can not prove this. Would you kindly help me to do this or provide me any link or useful reference, from where i can get the help.

Comment: $\exp(\theta A)=1+\theta A+\theta^2A^2/2+...=(1+\theta 1/2+\theta^4 1/4!+...)+(\theta A+\theta^3A^3/3!+...)=\cosh(\theta 1)+\sinh(\theta A)$, because all the even powers of $A$ become $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.